# Why does a child of an absolutely positioned element not expand its parent width on overflow-y?

Tags: html, css, overflow, absolute

I have an absolutely positioned element attached to the body of a page. It does not have limitations on its height or width. I have child of the absolute element that contains a list and it's height is limited on the y-axis. This listing can be variable in length and width so I would prefer not to use any hard-set paddings or margins nor "overflow-y: scroll" because the scroll bar will show even when not needed.

```
<style>
  .the-absolute {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .the-list {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100px; /* arbitrary limit for example */
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="the-absolute">
    <div class="the-list">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Year</div>
      <div>Studio</div>
      <div>Worldwide</div>
      <div>Domestic</div>
      <div>Budget</div>
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Year</div>
      <div>Studio</div>
      <div>Worldwide</div>
      <div>Domestic</div>
      <div>Budget</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would expect the width of the child element to expand the parent width while accommodating the scroll bar. Instead, the content of the longest list items is overlapped by the scroll bar on the right.

This works as I would expect in Chrome, but does not seem to play nice in IE11 (surprise!), Firefox or Safari.

I am a bit baffled here and would appreciate a better understanding of how absolute positioning affects the children of an element and if there is a way I can have dynamic (i.e. no hard-set margins, widths, etc) list that will be scrollable if it hits a certain threshold without overlapping the content.

I have tried multiple iterations and wrapping elements but something about the absolute positioning causes this. I can hack it using JS but would prefer a pure CSS solution. I just assume there is some detail I am missing or I lack the right combination of keywords to find the solution via google/stackoverflow.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the document flow, so they aren't really "in" their parent element anymore. They therefore do not affect the parent's dimensions.

Comment: While that is true, the parent in this case is the absolutely positioned element (and the child is in the flow that's established by that absposed element), so the document flow doesn't enter the discussion at all.

Comment: I apologize, that may have been my wording in the question, but this really is as @BoltClock mentioned about the parent (that is an absolutely positioned block element) not expanding to accommodate the scroll bar of the child element when the child exceeds its maximum height.